# Firestore update rule intervenes with create

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want users to be able to create a message (with contact form), but not allow them to read or update. I am adding a new contact as follows:

```
app.firestore().collection("messages").add({
            name: this.state.name,
            subject: this.state.subject,
            message: this.state.message});
```

With the following security rules this is allowed:

```
match /messages/{message}{
    allow read, delete: if request.auth.uid=="<SOME_ID>";
    allow create: if true;
}
```

But when I add an update rule like below, I get an unsufficient permission error when adding a new message.

```
match /messages/{message}{
    allow read, delete, update: if request.auth.uid=="<SOME_ID>";
    allow create: if true;
}
```

If I move the update rule below the create, this still doesn't work. But have tried, to set update to "always allow/true" after which the add action works again.

It therefore seems that Firestore somehow looks at the strictest rule out of the update and create rules, but only if the rule for update is explicitly defined. Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit:

```
match /messages/{message}{
allow read, delete: if request.auth.uid=="<SOME_ID>";
allow create: if true;  allow update: if false  }
```

Does not lead to permission issues.. So the behaviour seems specific to the type of check I am doing here..

Comment: This is confusing. An update rule shouldn't at all affect the code you're showing, because it's always going to create a new document with a new ID.  Update only applies to the modification of existing documents.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you think that this could be a bug? Or do you have any hints as to what you would try or look at in terms of my set up?

Comment: If you have solid reproduction steps, you could file a bug. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I found the solution, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run in to a similar issue in the future. The issue was, that the request did not contain an auth property. For some reason Firebase was checking the condition for the update case, and was testing:

```
request.auth.uid=="<SOME_ID>"
```

In the back this must have led to a: "trying to read property uid of null" error and crashed.

```
function isAdmin() {
     return request.auth != null
            && request.auth.uid=="<SOME_ID>";
}
....
allow update: if isAdmin();
```

Solves it